# There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'id' of xxx

Tags: c#, .net-5

I'm trying to instantiate this class:

the class:

```
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

public class GroceryItemTag
{
    [JsonConstructor]
    public GroceryItemTag(string name, GroceryItemTagEnum id, int iconCodePoint)
    {
        Id = id;
        IconCodePoint = iconCodePoint;
        Name = name;
    }

    public GroceryItemTagEnum Id { get; set; }
    public int IconCodePoint { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'id' of 'GroceryItemTag.GroceryItemTag(GroceryItemTagEnum, int, string)'
```

Here I am trying to instantiate the class (the enums are ints):

```
    builder.Entity<GroceryItemTag>().HasData(
        new GroceryItemTag[] {
        new GroceryItemTag(
            "Baby & Child",
            GroceryItemTagEnum.BabyAndChild,
            0xf77c
        ),
        new GroceryItemTag(
            "Baking",
            GroceryItemTagEnum.Baking,
            0xf563
        ),...
```

GroceryItemTagEnum:

```
public enum GroceryItemTagEnum
{
  BabyAndChild = 1,
  Baking,
  Bathroom,
  BeerAndWine,
  Condiments,
  Confectionary,  
  Cooking,
  Dessert,
  Drinks,
  FauxDairy,
  FauxMeat,
  FauxSeafood,
  FridgeAndDeli,
  Frozen,
  HealthFood,
  HouseHold,
  Other,
  Pantry,
  Pet,
}
```

the db context:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.Json;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking;

namespace Vepo.Domain
{
    public class VepoContext : DbContext
    {
        public VepoContext(DbContextOptions<VepoContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Entity<GroceryItemGroceryStore>().HasKey(table => new
            {
                table.GroceryItemId,
                table.GroceryStoreId
            });

            builder.Entity<MenuItemRestaurant>().HasKey(table => new
            {
                table.MenuItemId,
                table.RestaurantId
            });

            builder.Entity<GroceryItemTag>()
            .Property(tag => tag.Id)
            .ValueGeneratedNever();

            builder.Entity<MenuItemTag>()
            .Property(tag => tag.Id)
            .ValueGeneratedNever();

            builder.Entity<GroceryItemTag>().HasData(
                new GroceryItemTag[] {
                new GroceryItemTag(
                    "Baby & Child",
                    GroceryItemTagEnum.BabyAndChild,
                    0xf77c
                ),
                new GroceryItemTag(
                    "Baking",
                    GroceryItemTagEnum.Baking,
                    0xf563
                ),
                new GroceryItemTag (
                    "Beer & Wine",
                    GroceryItemTagEnum.BeerAndWine,
                    0xf4e3
                ),
                new GroceryItemTag (
                    "Condiments",
                    GroceryItemTagEnum.Condiments,
                    0xf72f
                ),
                new GroceryItemTag (
                    "Confectionary",
                    GroceryItemTagEnum.Confectionary,
                    0xf819
                ),
                new GroceryItemTag (
                    "Cooking",
                    GroceryItemTagEnum.Cooking,
                    0xe01d
                ),
                new GroceryItemTag (
                    "Dessert",
                    GroceryItemTagEnum.Dessert,
                    0xf810
                ),
                new GroceryItemTag (
                    "Drinks",
                    GroceryItemTagEnum.Drinks,
                    0xf804
                ),
                new GroceryItemTag (
                    "Faux Meat",
                    GroceryItemTagEnum.FauxMeat,
                    0xf814
                ),
                new GroceryItemTag (
                    "Faux Dairy",
                    GroceryItemTagEnum.FauxDairy,
                    0xf7f0
                ),
                new GroceryItemTag (
                    "Faux Seafood",
                    GroceryItemTagEnum.FauxSeafood,
                    0xf7fe
                ),
                new GroceryItemTag (
                    "Fridge & Deli",
                    GroceryItemTagEnum.FridgeAndDeli,
                    0xe026
                ),
                new GroceryItemTag (
                    "Frozen",
                    GroceryItemTagEnum.Frozen,
                    0xf7ad
                ),
                new GroceryItemTag (
                    "Bathroom",
                    GroceryItemTagEnum.Bathroom,
                    0xe06b
                ),
                new GroceryItemTag (
                    "Health Food",
                    GroceryItemTagEnum.HealthFood,
                    0xf787
                ),
                new GroceryItemTag (
                    "Household",
                    GroceryItemTagEnum.HouseHold,
                    0xf898
                ),
                new GroceryItemTag (
                    "Pantry",
                    GroceryItemTagEnum.Pantry,
                    0xf7eb
                ),
                new GroceryItemTag (
                    "Pet",
                    GroceryItemTagEnum.Pet,
                    0xf6d3
                ),
                new GroceryItemTag (
                    "Other",
                    GroceryItemTagEnum.Other,
                    0xf39b
                }});

            builder.Entity<MenuItemTag>().HasData(
                new MenuItemTag[] {
                new MenuItemTag {
                    Name = "American",
                    Id = MenuItemTagEnum.American,
                    IconCodePoint = 0xf803
                },
                new MenuItemTag {
                    Name = "Asian",
                    Id = MenuItemTagEnum.Asian,
                    IconCodePoint = 0xf823
                },
                new MenuItemTag {
                    Name = "Bakery",
                    Id = MenuItemTagEnum.Bakery,
                    IconCodePoint = 0xf705
                },
                new MenuItemTag {
                    Name = "Barbecue",
                    Id = MenuItemTagEnum.Barbecue,
                    IconCodePoint = 0xf80f
                },
                new MenuItemTag {
                    Name = "Breakfast",
                    Id = MenuItemTagEnum.Breakfast,
                    IconCodePoint = 0xe002
                },
                new MenuItemTag {
                    Name = "Cafe",
                    Id = MenuItemTagEnum.Cafe,
                    IconCodePoint = 0xf6c5
                },
                new MenuItemTag {
                    Name = "Chinese",
                    Id = MenuItemTagEnum.Chinese,
                    IconCodePoint = 0xf823
                },
                new MenuItemTag {
                    Name = "Deli",
                    Id = MenuItemTagEnum.Deli,
                    IconCodePoint = 0xf81f
                },
                new MenuItemTag {
                    Name = "Desserts",
                    Id = MenuItemTagEnum.Desserts,
                    IconCodePoint = 0xf551
                },
                new MenuItemTag {
                    Name = "European",
                    Id = MenuItemTagEnum.European,
                    IconCodePoint = 0xf7a2
                },
                new MenuItemTag {
                    Name = "Fish & Chips",
                    Id = MenuItemTagEnum.FishAndChips,
                    IconCodePoint = 0xf7fe
                },
                new MenuItemTag {
                    Name = "Indian",
                    Id = MenuItemTagEnum.Indian,
                    IconCodePoint = 0xf156
                },
                new MenuItemTag {
                    Name = "French",
                    Id = MenuItemTagEnum.Fench,
                    IconCodePoint = 0xf7f6
                },
                new MenuItemTag {
                    Name = "German",
                    Id = MenuItemTagEnum.German,
                    IconCodePoint = 0xf820
                },
                new MenuItemTag {
                    Name = "Greek",
                    Id = MenuItemTagEnum.Greek,
                    IconCodePoint = 0xf68b
                },
                new MenuItemTag {
                    Name = "Health Food",
                    Id = MenuItemTagEnum.HealthFood,
                    IconCodePoint = 0xf81e
                },
                new MenuItemTag {
                    Name = "Italian",
                    Id = MenuItemTagEnum.Italian,
                    IconCodePoint = 0xf817
                },
                new MenuItemTag {
                    Name = "Japanese",
                    Id = MenuItemTagEnum.Japanese,
                    IconCodePoint = 0xf56a
                },
                new MenuItemTag {
                    Name = "Kebab",
                    Id = MenuItemTagEnum.Kebab,
                    IconCodePoint = 0xf821
                },
                new MenuItemTag {
                    Name = "Kiwi",
                    Id = MenuItemTagEnum.Kiwi,
                    IconCodePoint = 0xf535
                },
                new MenuItemTag {
                    Name = "Korean",
                    Id = MenuItemTagEnum.Korean,
                    IconCodePoint = 0xf159
                }});


            builder.Entity<GroceryItem>()
            .Property(e => e.Tags)
            .HasConversion(
                v => JsonSerializer.Serialize(v, null),
                v => JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<GroceryItemTag>>(v, null),
                new ValueComparer<IList<GroceryItemTag>>(
                    (c1, c2) => c1.SequenceEqual(c2),
                    c => c.Aggregate(0, (a, v) => HashCode.Combine(a, v.GetHashCode())),
                    c => (IList<GroceryItemTag>)c.ToList()));

        }

        public DbSet<GroceryItem> GroceryItems { get; set; }
        public DbSet<GroceryItemGroceryStore> GroceryItemGroceryStores { get; set; }
        public DbSet<MenuItemRestaurant> MenuItemRestaurants { get; set; }
        public DbSet<MenuItem> MenuItems { get; set; }
        public DbSet<GroceryStore> GroceryStores { get; set; }
        public DbSet<GroceryItemTag> GroceryItemTags { get; set; }
        public DbSet<MenuItemTag> MenuItemTags { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Restaurant> Restaurants { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Clicking go to definition does go to the same GroceryItemTag. It used to be like this:

```
public class GroceryItemTag
{
    public GroceryItemTagEnum Id { get; set; }
    public int IconCodePoint {get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

But I changed it from that.

Hover error:

[image]

Why am I getting this error?

Try fully qualified name:

[image]

I added GroceryItemTag to `namespace Vepo.Domain`. Now when I click go to definition on `GroceryItemTag` it takes me to the constructor of GroceryItemTag. And go to definition of GRoceryItemTag.GroceryItemTag says no definition found.

Comment: Huh. The method signature in the error is different to your constructor signature. That's weird.

Comment: Is there an Extension method somewhere to cast from the Enum to an Int? You should include some or all of the definition for GroceryTagEnum but check the namespace, in C# 5 it's probably trying to do pattern matching due to another error causing DLLs to not compile first.

Comment: Please review [MCVE] guidance on posting code... In particular JSON that you presumably want to read is missing from the question... along with JSON related code... Code as shown in the post compiles perfectly fine... and runs (assuming basic `public enum GroceryItemTagEnum {Baking,BabyAndChild };` and ignoring unknown `builder` part)

Comment: Thanks @AlexeiLevenkov but no json here...

Comment: @JohnG it just means that somewhere else is a competing definition, or a similarly named type. Either way, only OP can figure this out with all the code in front of them.

Comment: I suspect this has something to do with your comment _the enum is an int_ and it looks like you have mapped the enum as an entity in its own right, which is possible, but I would not recommend it and I don't have a good example in any of my working code bases where I have done that since EF4, it just complicates things that EF will do for you automatically if you do not try to FK with enums

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on `GroceryItemTag` in `new GroceryItemTag`, then <kbd>Go To Defintion</kbd> and make sure that VS has resolved the correct definition matching your `JsonConstructor`.

This type of error looks like a namespace issue, but eitherway your code is clearly ambigous to the compiler.

Also try using the fully qualifed type name in your `new` expression, it might help identify the conflict.

```
builder.Entity<GroceryItemTag>().HasData(
        new Vepo.Domain.GroceryItemTag[] {
        new Vepo.Domain.GroceryItemTag(
            "Baby & Child",
            GroceryItemTagEnum.BabyAndChild,
            0xf77c
        ),
        new Vepo.Domain.GroceryItemTag(
            "Baking",
            GroceryItemTagEnum.Baking,
            0xf563
        ),...
```

---

Because you said c# 5, I want to say it has something to do with pattern matching, but I cannot replicate it.

Comment: When I right click go to definition it goes to the correct definition but when I try to use fully qualified name it doesn't exist, see the new bottom of my question for full details of that.

Comment: So it should actually be `new Vepo.Domain.GroceryItemTag(...` the new syntax you have is now invalid. (Without the dots though ;) )